# Different notations for complexity of algorithms

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science

Why is Big O notation (as opposed to a different kind of notation or metric) so commonly used to describe an algorithm? Why is it used so much more frequently than, for example, Big Omega or Big Theta notation?

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. Also, why is this tagged [python] and not [algorithm], for example?

Comment: I'm confused - what do you mean "most of the time people use notations?" What else would we use? By definition, any time you write something down it's a notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I think that people are probably the most familiar with this notation. The additional notation isn't always necessary anyway. For example, saying that a linear search is O(n) and Omega(1) isn't all *that* much more concise than saying that a linear search is O(n) in the worst case and O(1) in the best case.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer my answer my question :-)  . And I got The Idea about Big o notation and i 100% agree with your answer  because saying that a linear search is O(n) and Omega(1) isn't all that much more concise . Big O notation is good cause it always say the upper bound any one can understand function is grow less than or equal to that.